Alkaline + Sweat + heat = cat piss?
Back in the 70s my Army unit spent three days in the Arizona desert, temperatures reached over 110°, we only told to only bring one set of camouflage fatigue. After the maneuvers we were bussed to the AZ National Guard Depot, which was not air conditioned. There we secured our weapons and Stuffed those fatigues in high school looking lockers, showered, then took off for two days of some R&R. Well, when we turned and reopened those lockers, we were hit in the face with the worse Ammonia cat piss smell we were ever exposed to. We had to wear those fatigues smelling like cat piss in the plane back to Bragg. So what exactly was the Chemical Metamorphosis that went on there? Cuz boy did we stink!

"Chemical Metamorphosis" ;p

Sweat contains urea. When exercising, the amounts excreted increases due to metabolism.
The formula of urea is $\ce{CO(NH2)2}$. Urease, a family of common enzymes found in many bacteria, fungi, plants and some animals, breaks down urea catlaytically: $\ce{CO(NH2)2 + H2O -> CO2 + 2NH3}$, i.e, carbon dioxide and ammonia.
